# How to check used language percentage in Android Studio project

Tags: android, android-studio, apk

When we upload a project on GitHub it tells us the percentage of language used in that project. Is there any other option to check that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If you could use VS Code, you could try [VS Code Counter](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=uctakeoff.vscode-counter)
2. A free tool [SLOCCount](https://dwheeler.com/sloccount/)